# How to extract group count from dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to get the count of groups which is same 'id' and 'name'

Input:

```
myd = {
  "Items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "ABC",
      "value": 666
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "ABC",
      "value": 89
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "DEF",
      "value": 111
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "GHI",
      "value": 111
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
The count of {'id':1, 'name': 'ABC' } is 2
The count of {'id':2, 'name': 'DEF' } is 1
The count of {'id':3, 'name': 'GHI' } is 1
```

for total length we can get by `len(myd)` for single key its `len(myd['id'])`

How to get the count for the combination of `id` and `name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good candidate for [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) usage:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

myd = {'Items': [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'ABC', 'value': 666},
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'ABC', 'value': 89},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'DEF', 'value': 111},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'GHI', 'value': 111}]
}

grouper = itemgetter('id', 'name')

for i, v in groupby(sorted(myd['Items'], key=grouper), key=grouper):
    print(f"the count for {dict(id=i[0], name=i[1])} is {len(list(v))}")
```

Comment: how to extract only for `id`

Comment: means there i want grouper = itemgetter('id')

Comment: i tried with `for i, v in groupby(myd['Items'], key=grouper):
   print(f"the count for {dict(id=i)} is {len(list(v))}")`, its not coming properly

Comment: @sim What is expected?

Comment: same output, because for `id` 1 there are 2,  `id` 2 there are 1,  `id` 3 there are 1

Comment: `grouper = itemgetter('id')`

`for i, v in groupby(myd['Items'], key=grouper):
   print(f"the count for {dict(id=i)} is {len(list(v))}")`

Comment: @sim yes, this is how groupby works. You pass a key (in our case 'id') then groupby groups elements by that key for later processing.

Comment: @sim For groupby to work, your data mus tbe sorted wrt to the grouping function. Is it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and set both `'id'` and `'name'` as tuple keys. In this way, the `OrderedDict` automatically groups the dictionaries with same `'id'` and `'name'` values in order:

```
myd = {'Items': [
{'id':1, 'name': 'ABC', 'value': 666},
{'id':1, 'name': 'ABC', 'value': 89},
{'id':2, 'name': 'DEF', 'value': 111 },
{'id':3, 'name': 'GHI', 'value': 111 }]
}

from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict()
for d in myd['Items']:
    od.setdefault((d['id'], d['name']), set()).add(d['value'])

for ks, v in od.items():
    print("The count of {{'id': {}, 'name': {}}} is {}".format(ks[0], ks[1], len(v)))
```

Output:

```
The count of {'id': 1, 'name': ABC} is 2
The count of {'id': 2, 'name': DEF} is 1
The count of {'id': 3, 'name': GHI} is 1
```

Comment: what is .add(d['value']), is it required, if other keys are present, is this code work

Comment: @sim It is just a value to be used for counting. It can be any one of the keys that you don't want to group by. You can have many other keys for example, but you can still only use ``'value'`` as the "counter".

Comment: cod not working for myd = {'Items': [
{'id':1, 'name': 'ABC', 'dd':3},
{'id':1, 'name': 'ABC'},
{'id':2, 'name': 'DEF'},
{'id':3, 'name': 'GHI'}]
}

Comment: @sim The code does require every dictionary to have at least 3 keys in common. That's what I see from your question.

Comment: @sim I suggest you to first add an arbitrary ``'value'`` value to the dictionaries that do not have the ``'value'`` key. Then you can use my code.